# No puedo invocar clase de mi referencia web

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, webservice

Tengo un proyecto en el cual estoy añadiendo mejoras pero tengo el siguiente problema:

- Mi WS está en un proyecto de C# y mi aplicativo de escritorio en vb. el cual llama y consume a mi ws.
- Acabo de crear algunas clase nuevas como ejemplo "beAyudantes" en mi ws en la capa entidad donde defino parámetros de las variables: debidamente encapsuladas

  ```
  public class beAyudantes
  {

      private String sCodigo = " ";
      private String sNombres = " ";
      private String sApellidos = " ";.

  .

  .

      public String Codigo
      {
          get
          { return this.sCodigo; }
          set
          { this.sCodigo = value; }

      }
  ```

Luego actualizo la referencia web en mi aplicación de escritorio (posterior a la compilación y ejecución del ws en forma local) pero no logro llamar a la clase `beAyudantes` me indica que dicha clase de mi `reference.vb` ubicado en la referencia web no está definida.

```
    Dim oWS As New localhost.Service
    Dim oBeAyud As New localhost.beAyudante (aquí sale el error no encuentra beAyudante)
```

Quien me puede apoyar a encontrar el porque no puedo invocar la clase nueva que he creado para poder utilizarla en mi aplicativo.

Adjunto imágenes

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGiHs.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGiHs.jpg

[image: Nueva clase creada en ws]

[image: Se invoca llamar a la clase beAyudante]

Answer (score -1):

Valida que usas esa clase como respuesta o parametro en algun WebMethod que expone el servicio

si es asi, puedes verificar que el intellisense del Visual Studio al usar

```
var result = oWS.NombreWebMetod(...)
```

te muestra el uso de esa clase

Si solo lo defines pero no interviene como parte del servicio no se actualiza en el cliente, por eso valida que no solo la declares debes usarla en el servicio

Comment: Hola Leandro. Esto parece un comentario ya que le das instrucciones para que compruebe ciertas cosas. Eso deberias decirselo bajo la pregunta y una vez claro, redactar una respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b cual es el parametro que usas para indicar que es un comentario, solo porque uso el verbo "valida que usas" en lugar de "Tienes que usar", si le cambio de verbo ya no seria un comentario ?

Comment: Si, la redacción es importante. Muchas preguntas pueden ser cerradas o reabiertas cambiando solo verbos. Además pones *"si es así"* también indica que no sabes la situación actual con lo que estás adivinando. Y puede que tu prediccion sea acertada basada en tu experiencia pero por eso digo, mejor aclarar en la pregunta y responder en la respuesta. Un saludo